# VS Code gets very laggy every time I call numpy

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, lag

I have only recently faced this issue. Before this I have been using the numpy library extensively and never faced this problem. But now, for some reason, every time I want to type any command that has np. with it, it always lags really bad. It would freeze my PC for 1-2 seconds before spitting all the words I typed. Is this some kind of update issue or? I am using Python 3.11.5 with Anaconda.

An example of when this happens:

```
xi = np.linspace(0,10,101)
```

Which should work perfectly fine, but it would lag on my PC by the time I type the "."

Here's a GIF showcasing my issue:
[np issue GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSTqH.gif)

- Tried reloading the environment, didn't fix it
- Tried reimporting the library, didn't fix it too

Comment: Please include your actual code.  Has anything changed from it working ok to now being laggy?

Comment: It happens whenever I type "np." e.g. when I try to type np.array, np.linspace, etc. The code is part of my bigger work here:https://github.com/lemslemslems/fuse_testing

In terms of has anything changed. Not that I know of. My last project before this one was: https://github.com/lemslemslems/cell_thermal_calculations2

Comment: VS Code has a lot of bells and whistles: does this happen on a _clean_ VS Code, without extensions?

Comment: Wow this actually fixed the issue! I removed extensions "rainbow indents" and "read pdf in vs code" and suddenly there is no more lagging issue. Thank you.